# How can I make sure that a cygwin call is finished?

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin

I am currently calling a "convert"-cygwin method from Python. It should convert a pdf to a png file. However if I call the convert method and directly try to access the resulting png, there is an issue since apparently the png was not fully realized yet.

My code:

```
import os
import cv2

cmd = 'set PATH="C:/cygwin64/bin";"%PATH%" && cd '+os.path.dirname(PDFPath)+' && run convert -density 300 '+os.path.basename(PDFPath)+' -quality 100 -alpha off '+ img_path
os.system(cmd)
img = cv2.imread(img_path,0)
```

If I do this, the png will actually be created, but img is None, since apparently at the time of the call imread() the image did not exist.

I have also tried something along the lines of

```
while not os.path.exists(img_path):
    time.sleep(10)
```

and then tried to imread(), which worked. Is there a way to make sure that the file does indeed exist before calling img_path?

I don't want to keep use time.sleep() as there is a slight change that at the end of the sleep the png is still not fully loaded from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add `-wait` as the first argument to the command you run via `run` (e.g. `run convert -wait -density ...`) to get `run` to wait until the command completes. See `man run` in cygwin for more info on the `run` command.